# Install4j: "Running Process Detected" screen for Mac?

Tags: install4j

When updating application on Windows Install4j has a great feature of notifying the user if the application is currently running: "Running Process Detected" screen. Is there a similar functionality for Mac ?

Comment: As of install4j 5.1, there is no such functionality, but it is planned for a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Run a script in the installer to call this shell script and set a warning screen to the user depending on the outcome:-

```
#!/bin/bash
PROCESS=YourApp.app
number=$(ps aux | grep $PROCESS | wc -l)
if [ $number -gt 1 ]
then
        echo Running;
else
    echo NotRunning;
fi
```